# Mocking an external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testunit, ruby-mocha

I'm new to testing strategies and mocking, and I'm having a tough time figuring out how to mock a call to an external service.  I'm sure it's something easy I'm missing, I just don't know what exactly.

I'm using the Braintree gem to charge for subscription services through the Braintree gateway, and I wanted to mock the Customer create method and Subscription create method in my UserController's create method.

A Customer.create method looks something like this:

```
  result = Braintree::Customer.create(
    :first_name => @creditcard.first_name,
    :last_name => @creditcard.last_name,
    :email => @user.email
    :credit_card => {
      ...
      }
    }
  )
```

This returns a Braintree::Successful result object, with the attributes of the processed result.

I figure I have to do something like:

```
Braintree::Customer.expects(:create).returns(...)
```

But what goes in the returns area?  Do I need to create my own mocked up Successful object with the attributes of a faked processed result, or is there an easier way to do all of that?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You need to return some object that either is or "quacks like" a Braintree::Customer

I sometimes just use an OpenStruct

Comment: Ahh, I think that's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for.  Just something to mimic the same basic structure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return an `OpenStruct` as suggested in the comment or a `stub` or `mock`, which is IMHO better and more useful for tests, because you can easily set expectations, like this:

```
Braintree::Customer.expects(:create).returns(mock(:save => true))
```

The returned mock will expect the `save` message (which may not make sense in this case, but should give you the idea).