# What is the proper way of mocking my controller 'create' action that includes an external API call with mocha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am having a little bit of a difficult learning curve to test a create controller action that calls an external api call with Rails, mocha, and webmock. Below is the following controller code that I want to test.

```
  def create
    @response = Cdnify.create_cdn_resource(cdn_params)

    if @response.parsed_response['resources']
      flash[:notice] = 'Successfully Created Resource.'
    else
      @response.parsed_response['errors'].each do |error|
        flash[:error] = "#{error['code']}" + ': ' + "#{error['message']}"
      end
    end

    redirect_to cdns_path(ssl_slug: @ssl_slug)
  end
```

It's a straight forward test but I'm getting particularly confused as to how to test this code especially when it comes to mocking the external api call. I've looked at these stackoverflow questions but am still having a difficult time in regards to making webmock stub the request and then going form there to my flash messages and redirects. Here are the resources I've used:

[Queston 1 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523753/how-do-i-mock-a-response-of-a-controller-that-redirects-to-an-external-api)
[Question 2 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332170/using-mocha-for-controller-in-functional-test-with-rspec)
[Question 3 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401199/mocking-an-external-api)

Now here is my test code:

```
describe 'create' do
  it 'correctly creates a cdn resource, redirects to cdns#index, and shows successful flash message' do
  params = {api_key: 'api_key_123456',
            resource_name: 'somewebsite', resource_origin: 'http://www.somewebsite.com' }

  ####### Is this correct in definition and where its placed in the code? #######

  ####### Do I have to use webmock to create by hand the response from vcr gem? #######
  Cdnify.expects(:create_cdn_resource).with(params)


  ###### Am I suppose to execute this? #######
  post :create, params: params

  assert flash[:notice]
end
```

end

I've peppered my questions in that little piece of code but I'm confused as to how the flow of the code should go? Am I mocking the `Cdnify` class method first and then call post? Do I even need to use `post` call in the code? When I do execute the `post` code, vcr doesn't know how to handle the request, so am I supposed to hand craft a `response`? And where does that go?

Basically, I could use some help on how to create this very basic test. I have a feeling that it should be simple, but I'm having a hard time trying to combine all this new information correctly and some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can use [`Object#stub_const`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest-stub-const/Object:stub_const) in minitest. In rspec-mocks you would just use a [partial double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/basics/partial-test-doubles) but [mocha has no equivalent](https://github.com/freerange/mocha/issues/13).

Comment: @max, where would I place the stub is where I'm getting stuck at. Is it before the `post` call or after? I fail the test when the mocking is before because the post request hasn't been made. When I place it afterwards, VCR breaks and tells me it doesn't know how to handle the request. I'm a little stuck here. Do you think you could provide some sample code?